# tokanizing words by space NLTK

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

What is the code to tokanize lines by words not sentences in nltk Natural language processing?

Like for sentence I am using this code by I want to tokanize based on words rather than sentences.

```
import nltk
text=" Hi how are you, how is live, what are you doing "
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
print(sent_tokenize(text))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have ready library for that as well you can use this code

```
import nltk
text=nltk.word_tokenize(" Don't hesitate to ask questions, every thing will be okey")
print(text)
```